# How do I resolve access denied aws s3 files?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

Im trying to make files on my s3 bucket (CSS JS files) accessible to a Django application running in heroku.

I think I have the settings.py configured correctly.

However when I try to make changes to permissions in the S3 bucket i get access denied.
[image: Access denied error]

I added cors and bucket policy is set to public.

Ultimately when I load the application from heroku Im getting 403 errors when trying to access the static files.

Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::NameOfBucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

CORs configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

[image: public access settings]
How can I get the permissions to make changes in the s3 bucket please?

Comment: Did you configured the **Block S3 Public Access** settings? It's quite new and adds another layer of protection on buckets that you'll need to disable to permit public access.

Comment: Edited the question to show public access settings, thanks

Comment: What did you click when you received the **Access Denied** message? If you have a Bucket Policy granting access, then there is no need to use the **Make Public** function. If you received the error when clicking _Make Public_, the error is because S3 Block Public Access is currently blocking ACLs. This is fine if you have a Bucket Policy.

Comment: I clicked on access control list >> Public Access. This also happens if I try to make an individual file public. I tried to create a bucket policy that makes it public but that fails too. arn:aws:s3:::nameOfBucket, arn:aws:s3:::nameOfBucket/*

Comment: If you wish to make a single bucket public, then you need to turn off the first two options in the S3 Block Public Access settings. This should _not_ be necessary if you have created a Bucket Policy. What makes you think that the bucket policy is not working correctly? Also, it is not a good idea to grant `s3:*` on a bucket to `*` — that is effectively granting the entire world permission to do _anything_ to the bucket (including deleting content, or uploading their entire movie collection). You probably only want to grant `s3:GetObject` permission.

Comment: The fact that when I try to visit the application, none of the css or js files are loading. In the browser console I get, net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden). This happens locally too.

Comment: Try turning off the 4th option in S3 Block Public Access.

Comment: That works! can you explain why that works. Ill also need to change s3:* to something more secure, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option is called **Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies**. When this was TRUE, it meant that the Bucket Policy only applied to the bucket owner.

For details, refer to: [Using Amazon S3 Block Public Access - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html)

These four new settings could be considered annoying because they are additional blockages on trying to make content public, but they are probably going to save many organizations a lot of embarrassment by preventing accidental public exposure of data.

Answer (score 1):

New S3 feature - S3 Public block might be blocking your request. You can look at your cloudtrail logs to get more details.
More details : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html

Also looking at your policy, you are allowing `s3:*` action on your bucket prefix to all AWS principals.
Generally, it is not good practice to open all S3 action to all AWS principals. Kindly review your need and scope down policies to achieve better security on your bucket objects.